# ColdFusion 10 HTTP SSL

Tags: ssl, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm running a site and several sub domains on ColdFuson 10 Standard, we have just upgraded from ColdFusion 9 where everything was working fine.

The sites have a wildcard ssl certificate installed so all the sub domains are secured. I'm making http calls between the sites but getting the `I/O Exception: peer not authenticated` error.

```
Charset [empty string]
ErrorDetail I/O Exception: peer not authenticated
Filecontent Connection Failure
Header  [empty string]
Mimetype    Unable to determine MIME type of file.
Responseheader    struct [empty]
Statuscode  Connection Failure. Status code unavailable.
Text    YES
```

I've installed the certificate in the correct key store and verified it's there using `keytool -list`and restarted, but still get the authentication error.

I know this is a common problem and is usually fixed by installing the certificate and there are workarounds for ColdFusion Enterprise but I'm struggling to get this working on Standard. Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you also on ColdFusion 9 Standard (not Enterprise)? I'm not aware of any changes for the `cfhttp` tag from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 10. Is your hardware the same or is ColdFusion 10 running on new servers? That particular error usually points to a certificate issue and/or invalid user credentials.

Comment: It's on new hardware, it's a brand new dedicated server running Windows 2012 SP2. CF9 was Standard running on Windows 2008 R2. I exported the certificate from the browser as a DER encoded binary X.509 (.CER) in order to import it into the key store. The certificate has the following path `GeoTrust Global CA > RapidSSL CA > *.domain.com` would I need to install any GeoTrust and RapidSSL certificates?

Comment: I don't think you should need to install the root certificates. I believe you would get a different error message if that were the case. Is there a stacktrace to go along with the error? Did you need to import the root certificates on your ColdFusion 9 server? When you imported the cert to the keystore did you restart the ColdFusion server (that is required to see the new cert)?

Comment: I've added the full dump of http call results to the main post. No stack trace only a log of the actual call in the `http.log`. On CF9 I didn't need to install any certificates. Yes restarted a few times, tried removing it and adding it a few times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many days of investigation I came across [this blog post](http://www.trunkful.com/index.cfm/2013/7/22/What-You-Need-To-Know-About-CFHTTP-SSL-and-SNI) which leads to [bug report #3598342](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3598342).

It turns out to be an issue on Windows 2012 servers running IIS 8. There is an option on the site binding to 'Require Server Name Indication' or 'SNI'. Turning this option off allows cfhttp to connect via https.

[image: Edit Site Binding]

It turns out this is an issue with the HttpClient library and has been fixed in builds 288845, 288846 and 290605. Which doesn't really help as the last update 13 only gives me build 287689.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue I have run across where I had to import the secure server certificate into coldfusion before it would allow me to connect.

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html

[Import Certificate for ColdFusion10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863292/import-certificate-for-coldfusion10)

Hope that helps. I know it helped me!

Comment: I didn't have this issue on CF 9, but once I upgraded to 10 I had to figure this out.

Comment: yeah that is what I'm currently experiencing. Thanks for the links. It's interesting that the keytool commands have changed slightly for CF10 I didn't know that and the old ones still seem to work. I've tried reinstalling the certificate but still no joy. I've tried DER encoded binary X.509 (.CER), Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER), X.509 Certificate (PEM) with no luck. I then tried installing CertMan and installing via the admin interface with the same results. I'm at a loss of what to try next.